Efficient inversion of $A^T A + B^T B$
Consider matrices $A \in \mathbb R^{k \times n}, B(\eta) \in \mathbb R ^{l \times n}$, where $B$ depend on some parameters $\eta$. The matrix $A$ will be fixed.
My problem is to compute
$$
(A^TA + B(\eta)^TB(\eta))^{-1}
$$
in an efficient manner, since $n$ is going to be large and I am going to compute this inverse multiple times, where $\eta$ changes.
We assume that $A^T A$ is invertible and also $B^TB$ is invertible for any $\eta$.
What is a fast and stable way of doing this, utilizing all the information?
Cleary we are to invert a symmetric positive definite matrix, so the solution always exists, but I believe the particular structure can be utilized to speed up inversion even further.
This particular square matrix is to be inverted, arising in numerous problems, for instance arising from many types of regularized linear regression/least squares -- then $\eta$ plays the role of a hyperparameter, that we may want to tune.
I suspect that using the Cholesky decompositions of $A^T A$ and $B^T B$ may yield some efficient results, or even the QR decomposition of $A, B$ but I struggle in finding any previous work on this.

I will answer my own question, though with an additional (important) detail.
The above problem appears (in my case) as:
$$
\Big(A^TA + B(\eta)^T B(\eta) \Big)^{-1} A^T y
$$
which is well-known to be the solution to the problem
$$
\min_x \| \begin{pmatrix} A \\ B(\eta) \end{pmatrix} x - \begin{pmatrix} y \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}  \| . 
$$
This appoints us to consider the QR factorization of
$$
\begin{pmatrix} A & y \\ B(\eta) & 0 \end{pmatrix} = QR
$$
The neat thing about this formulation, is that we can divide the factorization into two steps. The first step is the following, and can be executed only once:
$$
[A, y] = Q_d [R_{d1}, R_{d2}] . 
$$
Then what is left is to QR factorize
$$
\begin{pmatrix} R_{d1} & R_{d2} \\ B(\eta) & 0 \end{pmatrix} = Q_c R_c
$$
Then $R = R_c$. This is much more efficient when we should solve the equation several times for different values of $\eta$. Then the sub-matrices of $R$ (which is upper triangular) can be used to efficiently compute inverses and other aspects of the equation.
Given the assumptions, this is guaranteed to exist and be unique.
(Its been a while, so I decided to post what I have - maybe it can be used to solve the original problem?)
